# Using a name instead of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

This is how I wrap all my JavaScript:

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    var myFunction = function() {}
})(jQuery, window);
```

But now I have the need to call myFunction from outside of that closure.

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
    myFunction();
}, false);
```

Q: How do I name the self executing anonymous function so that I can call myFunction from the global scope?

Comment: "name the self executing anonymous function", wouldn't that make it not anonymous?

Comment: Yes, it would.  I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Do you know that if you don't put var when declaring a variable in js, this put it in the global object? This would make it available from anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the function to a property of whichever object/scope you want to use.

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    var myFunction = function() {};
    window.myFunction = myFunction;
})(jQuery, window);
```

You'd preferably want to return something from your IIFE that encapsulates all your 'exports' though.

```
var exports = (function($, window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    var myFunction = function() {};
    return {
        "myFunction": myFunction
    };
})(jQuery, window);

window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
    exports.myFunction();
}, false);
```

[AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) is helpful for this style of programming.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I see you're from Sheffield. I used to listen to Boagworld all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy, just attach your function to the global object (window):

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    var myFunction = function() {}
    window.myNamedFunction = myFunction;
})(jQuery, window);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a namespace and push that to the global scope.

```
window.yourNamespace = window.yourNamespace || {};
window.yourNamespace.myFunction = function() {};
```